# Populate data from dataset and show in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am working in VB.NET and I have a simple requirement:

I have added a MDB file to a DataSet and it contains 21 tables.

I have a DataGridView and a ComboBox on my form.

I was able to get the ComboBox populated with the table names available in the DataSet by iterating through `dataset.Tables`.

Now I want to the user to be able to select the table name from the ComboBox and then  populate the contents of that table.

I tried the following code:

```
Datagridview1.DataSource = dataset1
Datagridview1.DataMember = dataset1.tables(combobox1.selecteditem)
Datagridview1.Refresh()
```

But I only got the column headers. Then I read that I need a TableAdapter to populate the DataSet with that table. But if I use the TableAdapter then I won't be able to populate the table in a generic way.

Currently if I have to populate `TableA` then I will have to create an instance of `Dataset1TableAdapters.TableA` and then use it's `.Fill` property to populate the table. I will also have to use "Dataset1TableAdapters.TableB`. Is there a generic method to populate **any** table in the DataSet?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think the tag `generic-way-to-get-tablea` should stay...

Comment: no probs, i was just trying to improve visibility to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
Datagridview1.DataSource = dataset1.tables(combobox1.selecteditem)
```

Answer (score 1):

C# but easily convertible to VB.Net (I suppose):

```cs
String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\test.mdb""";
String tableName = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
String sqlSELECT = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", tableName);

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlSELECT, new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString));

DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet1;
DataGridView1.DataMember = dataSet1.Tables(tableName);
da.Fill(dataSet1, tableName);
```

I was just sketching a proof that "it can be done in a generic way" to your problem, you should elaborate and maybe come with something more elegant (and safe).

Comment: the solution seems elegant, but then may i ask why such a thing can't be done through an existing dataset? if all the table adapter does is to fill in the dataset with the table, and that too us specifying the query, there should be a way for doing via dataset as well..

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub BindData()

    With customersDataGridView
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = customersDataSet
        .DataMember = "Customers"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on your code example, specifically how it pertains to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify this answer. For Future Reference.

```
Public Class Form1   
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test.accdb;")

Private Sub Button1_Click

            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim table As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
            Dim sql As String = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", table)
            da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(table)
            da.Fill(DataSet, table)

End Sub
End Class
```

Not trying to Ressurect, but i thought the working version of this VB Script should be posted.

I would like to point out that the dataset is held by Visual Studio, hence the strange source string.